# Как ограничить видимость скрипта на определенной странице?

Tags: javascript, java, веб-программирование, jsf, primefaces

Подключаю скрипт с помощью `<h:outputScript name="js/js-file.js" library="java" />` он виден во всем проекте (на каждой странице). И на странице, где он не используется, вылезает:

> TypeError: XXX is undefined

Как ограничить видимость этого скрипта на определенной странице? Например, только на `page1.xhtml`.

Имеется ввиду, что `h:outputScript` прописывается в одном месте для всего проекта, и таких скриптов там много. Есть ли возможность как-то управлять их видимостью?

Comment: Можете показать пример кода, который должен выполняться только, условно, на странице `page1.xhtml`?

Comment: @Cheg `<h:form id="form1"> <p:panel id="Panel" /> <h:outputScript name="js/js-file.js" library="XXX" /> </h:form>`

Comment: @Cheg выше приведена вырезка кода из разметки страницы page1.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы подключаете в шаблоне, то можете написать `if` который будет проверять `URL` и блокировать подключение если адрес не `page_1`. Пример:

```
<head>
    <?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "page_1"): ?>
    <script src="YOUR_SCRIPT.js"></script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</head>
```

Вообще в разных фреймворках это можно сделать более элегантным способом.

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка, вероятнее всего, появляется, когда вы пытаетесь получить элемент по `id`, например, через `document.getElementById('form1')`, но элемента с `id="form1"` на странице нет нет.

Самый простой способ избежать этой ошибки - перед выполнением кода проверять, есть ли элемент на странице или нет:

```js
if (document.getElementById('form1').length != 0) {
  // ваш код
  console.log('элемент с id="form1" на странице есть');
}
```

```html
<div id="form1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Прописывать `<h:outputScript />` только на той странице где используется или более того только в том компоненте с которым загружается. Если принципиально нужно записать подключаемый скрипты в `<head>` то используйте:

```
<h:outputScript target="head"/>
```